# В чём ошибка при подсчёте времени

Tags: javascript

Нужно было создать обьект описывающий машину ,  а затем вычислить время за которое эта машина проедет переданное расстояние , с учётом того ,что через каждые 4 часа водителю нужен час отдыха. Но почему то не всегда показывает нужное значение. К примеру в этом случае он должен преодолеть расстояние за 12 часов,  но показывает 14

```js
function Car(producer, model, issueYear, averageSpeed) {
  this.producer = producer;
  this.model = model;
  this.issueYear = issueYear;
  this.averageSpeed = averageSpeed;

  this.timeDistance = function(distance) {
    let time = distance / this.averageSpeed;
    for (let i = 0; i < time; i++) {
      if (i % 4 == 0) {
        time++;
      }
    }
    console.log(time);
  };
}
let firstCar = new Car('Ferrari', 'F12', 2000, 40);
firstCar.timeDistance(400);
```

Comment: может потому что остаток от деления нуля на 4 это ноль? :) то же самое на конце маршрута. Водитель перед выездом отдохнул и после приезда

Comment: каждые полные  4 часа, кроме последних добавят 2 часа. значит, делим на 4, округляем вверх, вычитаем единицу и умножаем на 2

Comment: 160/4 = 4 с округлением вниз тоже 4, а нужно 3, теперь 161/4 = 4,... c округлением вниз 4 и нужно 4. а если оба округлить вверх и вычесть один, получится 3 и 4

Comment: Вобщем дробная часть должна дать единицу а не ноль

Comment: Почему я решил что два часа отдыха :)) Не надо умножать на два

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объяснения в комментариях даны

```js
function Car(producer, model, issueYear, averageSpeed) {
  this.producer = producer;
  this.model = model;
  this.issueYear = issueYear;
  this.averageSpeed = averageSpeed;

  this.timeDistance = function(distance) {
    let time = distance / this.averageSpeed;
    time += Math.ceil(time/4)-1;
    return time;
  };
}

let firstCar = new Car('Ferrari', 'F12', 2000, 40);
console.log(firstCar.timeDistance(400));
console.log(firstCar.timeDistance(160));
console.log(firstCar.timeDistance(161));
```

Answer (score 3):

Каждые полные четыре часа, кроме последних, добавляют час времени.

Нам нужно найти количество полных четверок и добавить столько часов. За исключением случая, когда изначальное время кратно 4

```js
function Car(producer, model, issueYear, averageSpeed) {
  this.producer = producer;
  this.model = model;
  this.issueYear = issueYear;
  this.averageSpeed = averageSpeed;

  this.timeDistance = function(distance) {
    let time = distance / this.averageSpeed;
    let delta = Math.floor(time / 4);
    if (Math.abs(delta * 4 - time) < 1E-6)
      delta--;
    time += delta;
    return time;
  };
}

let firstCar = new Car('Ferrari', 'F12', 2000, 40);
const time = firstCar.timeDistance(400);
console.log(time);
```

Comment: если это `if (Math.abs(delta * 4 - time) < 1E-6)` проверка на кратность 4, то я не понимаю, почему вас плюсуют